# getting distinct users from the resultset and string concat on other fields

Tags: groovy

I have a Sql ResultSet from a query. It has following fields: username, department, ..responsibility.
There are repeated username with different values for deptmt and responsblty. I want to get a map/list of unique usernames with a list of departments and responsibilities for each user in the resultset

So if

```
       resultset =     (Sam, dept1,.. resp1),
                       (Tom, dept1,..resp3),
                       (Sam,dept2,..resp2),
                       (Tom,dept3,..resp3)...etc
```

the output should be

```
 finalList = [["Sam", "dept1,dept2", "resp1,resp2"],["Tom", "dept1,dept3", "resp3"]]
```

Things to note: 
1) There may be n columns which are variable (column list read from a property file) so the code to be adaptable. _ not reqired for now, its a fixed list right now
2)All values enclosed in double quotes and seperated by comma.
3) For tom responsibility contains only resp3 since its repeated...i.e unique values in the list.

How do I convert the resultset?
Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, you'd be throwing away the relationship between department and responsibility for that person, right?  i.e. Sam is a resp1 for dept1, and a resp2 for dept2, but once you convert him you no longer know what he did for each department.

Comment: yes I dont need the relationship to be maintained, I finally want to write the output to a csv which is read by an application and it needs the data in this format. thats all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shorter alternative to Bill's solution would be:

```
def data = [ ['Sam', 'dept1','resp1'],
            ['Tom', 'dept1','resp3'],
            ['Sam', 'dept2','resp2'],
            ['Tom', 'dept2','resp4'] ]

def output = data.groupBy { it[0] }.collect { name, vals -> 
  $/"$name", "${vals*.getAt( 1 ).join(',')}", "${vals*.getAt( 2 ).join(',')}"/$
}

output.each {
  println it
}
```

Which prints:

```
"Sam", "dept1,dept2", "resp1,resp2"
"Tom", "dept1,dept2", "resp3,resp4"
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but getting double quotes in the code while forming the output is important since that will clear the seperation between the value seperator in the column list and between the column fields

Comment: Also the last time the grouping happens, it should not join(,)..maybe I can handle this seperatley again, but will this modification work?...[ '\"'+name + '\"', '\"'+vals*.getAt( 1 )?.join(',') +'\"', '\"'+vals*.getAt( 2 )?.join(',')+'\"' ]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is really the most terse answer ever possible for this... :). May I ask how can I get good at closures? and which books do you recommend for this?

Comment: Thanks for the "groupBy" method... didn't know that one.

Comment: @pri_dev This isn't so much a `Closure` thing, it's just knowing some of the methods that let you manipulate Collections in Groovy.  There's a good [presentation of a lot of them here](http://trygvea.github.com/groovy-collection-api-presentation/), ad there are new ones added all the time (such as [collate](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate%28int%29) that was added with Groovy 1.8.6).

Comment: @pri_dev The best place to look, is the javadocs for [List](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html), [Collection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html), and [Iterator](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Iterator.html). Then I just find one that's interesting and practice using it to see how it works. As far as books go, the best is still Groovy in Action (the [Second edition of which](http://manning.com/koenig2/) is in Early Access on Manning.com)

Answer (score 1):

This should get you pretty close.  Note that the final output doesn't have the quotes in it (Groovy doesn't print those for strings). Looking at the code, you can see that the "output" is a Collection of Lists, each with 3 items: the name, the comma-sep list of department strings, then the comma-sep list of responsibility strings.

BTW, you may want to use something other than comma in the inner-strings, if you want to create a comma-sep list as the final output.

```
def data = [ ['Sam', 'dept1','resp1'],
            ['Tom', 'dept1','resp3'],
            ['Sam', 'dept2','resp2'],
            ['Tom', 'dept2','resp4'] ]


def tmpmap = [:]
data.each { inputrow ->
    def name = inputrow[0]
    def curlist = tmpmap[name]
    if ( curlist == null ) { // first time seeing this name
        curlist = [name,inputrow[1],inputrow[2]]
        tmpmap.put( name, curlist );
    } else { // seen this name before
        curlist[1] += ',' + inputrow[1]
        curlist[2] += ',' + inputrow[2]
    }
}
output = tmpmap.values()
println output
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. the only thing is it will become impossible to seperate columns and multiple entries in each column because without double quotes all seperators are supposed to be commas(,) and there is no nesting of values in the list to seperate it out.